# Invalid parameters using ArcPy dissolve and statistics_fields

Tags: arcpy, dissolve

I am trying to use the Dissolve_management tool using ArcPy. I keep getting an error that reads "Parameters are not valid.", and I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Here is the code:

```
env.workspace = "H:/Data/"
input = "Analysis/mtbs_state_2000/al.shp"
output = "Analysis/2000_dissolved/al.shp"
statistics_fields = [["km2", "SUM"], ["HU90", "SUM"]]
arcpy.Dissolve_management(input, output, "Fire_ID", statistics_fields)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `["Fire_ID"]` (with brackets) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck :/

Comment: `env.workspace` shouldn't have a trailing slash.

Comment: Nice catch Paul. However, I'm still seeing the issue

Comment: Are those the actual field names or are they aliases?

Comment: Your code works for me in 10.2.2. So there's something else going on.  What version of ArcGIS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Analysis` folder is not being accessed, try:

```
# also notice the double slashes throughout
env.workspace = "H:\\Data" 
input = env.workspace +"\\Analysis\\mtbs_state_2000\\al.shp"
output = env.workspace +"\\Analysis\\2000_dissolved\\al.shp"
statistics_fields = [["km2", "SUM"], ["HU90", "SUM"]]
arcpy.Dissolve_management(input, output, "Fire_ID", statistics_fields)
```

Comment: This is assuming the 'Analysis' folder is in 'H:/Data'

Comment: [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is your friend. Though, it kind of defeats the purpose of setting `env.workspace` if you are just going to concatenate it anyways....

Comment: Are you sure that double forward slashes ("//") will not itself cause a problem?  I know double backslashes is fine ("\\"), as well as single forward slash ("/") and lastly single backslashes ("\") but only with an `r` before the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yang. The ArcPy documentation uses the single forward slash notation, and I've used that with all my other scripts without any issues. But I tried your notation, still not working

Comment: Sorry.. @PolyGeo is right it is either double back slash("\\") or a single forward slash ("/") with an r in front of the path. For example: `env.workspace = r"H:/Data". I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Paul I agree, I was just giving a quick work around. What I usually do is set my 'env.workspace' to the folder that I want my results to go. And reference any input data by either giving a full path or setting other generic workspaces. like `input_ws = "path_to_folder"`